# Accordion menu stay open until it closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have accordion menu witch by default when page is loaded is closed and user must click on the menu to open it. How can I make it when page is loaded to be open and stay always open and to become closed when is clicked?
This is js

```
(function (window, $) {
'use strict';

// Cache document for fast access.
var document = window.document;

/************** Toggle Menu *********************/
$('a.toggle-menu').click(function(){
    $(".menu").slideToggle(400);
    return false;
});

/************** Open Different Pages *********************/
$(".menu a").click(function(){
    var id =  $(this).attr('class');
    id = id.split('-');
    $("#menu-container .content").hide();
    $("#menu-container #menu-"+id[1]).addClass("animated fadeInDown").show();
    return false;
});

$(".menu a.homebutton").click(function(){
    $(".menu").slideUp();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 769){  
        $(".menu a").click(function(){
            $(".menu").hide();
            return false;
        });
    }   
});

})(window, jQuery);
```

And this is the html for it

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
     <ul class="menu">
           <li><a class="homebutton" href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a class="show-1" href="#">Menu-1</a></li>
           <li><a class="show-2" href="#">Menu-2</a></li>
           <li><a class="show-3" href="#">Menu-3</a></li>
     </ul> <!-- /.menu -->
     <a href="#" class="toggle-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div> <!-- /.menu-wrapper -->
```

Update with `css`

```
.menu-wrapper {
    display: block;
}

.menu-wrapper ul.menu {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-wrapper ul.menu li {
    border-top: 1px solid #c7cdd8;
}

.menu-wrapper ul.menu li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    padding: 18px 30px;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu-wrapper a.toggle-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: #f5af95;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-wrapper a.toggle-menu i {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: You can change its height .css() when clicked and animate it back to 0 when it is closed

Comment: Ok, thank's. According to your comment I found [this](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and added `$( this ).height( ).css({ cursor: "auto",  });` but the menu is still not open when the page load. When I click and open it once is stay opened but on page load is closed. Can you help also with this?

Comment: Oh sorry missed that part where you want it to be open initially. Why dont you just set the height in the initial css?  like .menu-wrapper{ height:...}. It will initially have the height you want and again the click will take it back to closed. Please tell me if I got the question wrong

Comment: also you can do do $(this).css("height", "...px"). I made a typo sorry you dont necessary need .height()

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand where to put this..

Comment: can you post your css so we can create a fiddle. I can show you that way

Comment: Sure.. I have edited my question and added CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, If I got your question 100% correct. Here is the full code. If you need to add/remove something comment and I will change it. JS/Jquery is integrated into html code

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="john.css">

    <!--libraries-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu-wrapper">
         <ul class="menu">
               <li><a class="homebutton" href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a class="show-1" href="#">Menu-1</a></li>
               <li><a class="show-2" href="#">Menu-2</a></li>
               <li><a class="show-3" href="#">Menu-3</a></li>
         </ul> <!-- /.menu -->
         <a href="#" class="toggle-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div> <!-- /.menu-wrapper -->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var clicked= true;

            $(".menu-wrapper").click(function(){

                if(clicked){
                    $(".menu-wrapper ul.menu").css("display", "none");
                    clicked = false;
                }else{
                    $(".menu-wrapper ul.menu").css("display", "block");
                    clicked= true;
                }
            })
        })



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-wrapper {
display: block;
}

.menu-wrapper ul.menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
 }

.menu-wrapper ul.menu li {
    border-top: 1px solid #c7cdd8;
 }

.menu-wrapper ul.menu li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    padding: 18px 30px;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
}

 .menu-wrapper a.toggle-menu {
   display: block;
   background-color: #f5af95;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
.menu-wrapper a.toggle-menu i {
   padding: 10px 20px;
   font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: It's working just one last thing.. Now when I click on some menu item ( which is another page.php ) is loading new page but like I'm clicked on home button and I must click again on menu item to show me that page.. Is there and option when I click on menu item to load me that page not the Home part first.?

Comment: Awesome. Remember to accept the answer (click that tick icon) for future uses. I dont totally get your question. I think you modified your code, can you update it here or just open a new question with the updated code. Right now you <a> element have href #, which will send you back to the current page (home page). You might want to change it to page1.html or whatever it is if you havent already

Comment: Yes, I will accept just wanted to clarify this. This is the situation. You're on example.com/index.php . Then you click on the `Menu_1` normaly will and must load example.com/menu_1.php . The way how is working now is to load example.com/menu_1.php  but is showing the index.php page and you must click again on menu_1 to load you menu_1.php .. something is messing with this js menu..

Comment: That is strange. Do you set the hrefs or body dynamically ? Check the hrefs on index.php maybe it is just a simple mistake that you set the href of menu_1 to index.php or something ? I can not comment any further without seeing the actual code cuz right now all I have is a static menu bar that doesnt load any php files or anything.  Again my suggestion is that you open a new question with the most recent code. Send the link to the question in a comment. In that way other people can look at the current problem and help. Since this is an old question people are not seeing it probably.